# How we can mock a CoroutineDatabase in ktor?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, kmongo

I use the KMongo tool
How we can mock a Coroutine Database?
How can we mock our database in a koin module?

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks for guiding me

Methods I have tried and it has not worked:

**The first method:**

```
  single<CoroutineDatabase> {
      val client = Mockito.mock(CoroutineClient::class.java)
      client.getDatabase(CoreConstants.DATABASE_NAME)
  }
```

**The second method:**

```
    single<CoroutineDatabase> {
        val client = declareMock<CoroutineClient> {  }
        client.getDatabase(CoreConstants.DATABASE_NAME)
    }
```

Comment: I'm using https://www.testcontainers.org to create a database test container and that works pretty well for my Ktor project. There's a MongoDB module https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mongodb. Not sure if that works if you use KMongo on top of MongoDB. Also it's not multiplatform but my assumption is that the tests can run as JVM tests so this should be possible. Injecting the test database using Koin is straight forward assuming you're injecting the real database with Koin too.

Comment: Injection with Koin works well on a driver basis (inject the real driver or the test container driver). I just read up on KMongo. I'm not sure if you can configure a different driver than the two mentioned in the docs (sync/async driver). Worst case you could take the source code and add the testcontainers driver as a third option.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get this working with [MockK](https://mockk.io) with the following approach.

---

#### TLDR

Just use a mock of `MongoDatabase`/`MongoCollection<T>` and make their `coroutine` extension property return a mocked `CoroutineDatabase`/`CoroutineCollection<T>`. Also need to mock the actual `MongoDatabase::getCollection` to return the respective `MongoCollection<T>`.

---

Suppose we have this scenario.

```kotlin
data class User(val id: Int, val name: String)

class Service(private val myDatabase: CoroutineDatabase) {
    private val userCollection: CoroutineCollection<User> = myDatabase.getCollection("users")
    suspend fun getById(id: Int): User? = userCollection.findOneById(id)
}
```

Since `userCollection` is acquired by calling the [`inline`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html) method `CoroutineDatabase::getCollection` we need to mock all the code inside that `inline` because [inline methods cannot be mocked with MockK](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/27) (at the time of writing). Looking at [the method code](https://github.com/Litote/kmongo/blob/2edee31bb5276918f6a3f0b56aaf5c28f5898fc6/kmongo-coroutine-core/src/main/kotlin/org/litote/kmongo/coroutine/CoroutineDatabase.kt#L127)

```kotlin
inline fun <reified TDocument : Any> getCollection(
        collectionName: String = KMongoUtil.defaultCollectionName(TDocument::class)
    ): CoroutineCollection<TDocument> =
        database.getCollection(collectionName, TDocument::class.java).coroutine
```

It just calls `com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoDatabase::getCollection` and then uses [this extension property](https://github.com/Litote/kmongo/blob/2edee31bb5276918f6a3f0b56aaf5c28f5898fc6/kmongo-coroutine-core/src/main/kotlin/org/litote/kmongo/coroutine/CoroutineCollection.kt#L83) to map it to a `CoroutineCollection`. Notice it uses the field `database` from `CoroutineDatabase` which is a `MongoDatabase` (The `CoroutineDatabase` was previously obtain via a [similar extension property](https://github.com/Litote/kmongo/blob/2edee31bb5276918f6a3f0b56aaf5c28f5898fc6/kmongo-coroutine-core/src/main/kotlin/org/litote/kmongo/coroutine/CoroutineDatabase.kt#L36) for `MongoDatabase`).

```kotlin
val <T : Any> MongoCollection<T>.coroutine: CoroutineCollection<T> get() = CoroutineCollection(this)

val MongoDatabase.coroutine: CoroutineDatabase get() = CoroutineDatabase(this)
```

Having all of this we need to mock:

- Both `coroutine` extension properties on `MongoDatabase` and `MongoCollection<T>` (see [mocking extension properties with MockK](https://mockk.io/#extension-functions))
- The actual `MongoDatabase::getCollection` because `CoroutineDatabase::getCollection` is an `inline` function

```kotlin
// Arrange
val mockedMongoDd: MongoDatabase = mockk<MongoDatabase> {
    mockkStatic(MongoDatabase::coroutine)
    val that = this
    every { coroutine } returns mockk {
        every { database } returns that
    }
}

val mockedMongoCol: MongoCollection<User> = mockk<MongoCollection<User>> {
    mockkStatic(MongoCollection<T>::coroutine)
    val that = this
    every { ofType<MongoCollection<T>>().coroutine } returns mockk {
        every { collection } returns that
    }
}

every {
    mockedMongoDb.getCollection("users", User::class.java)
} returns mockedMongoCol

val mockedCoroutineDb = mockedMongoDb.coroutine
val mockedCoroutineCol = mockedMongoCol.coroutine

val service = Service(mockedCoroutineDb)
val expectedUser = User(2, "Joe")

coEvery {
    mockedCoroutineCol.findOneById(2)
} returns expectedUser

// Act
val actualUser = service.getById(2)

// Assert
assertEquals(expectedUser, actualUser)
```

Finally, one could make some methods like the following to hide this details from the test.

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Any> mockkCoroutineCollection(
    name: String? = null,
    relaxed: Boolean = false,
    vararg moreInterfaces: KClass<*>,
    relaxUnitFun: Boolean = false,
    block: MongoCollection<T>.() -> Unit = {}
): MongoCollection<T> = mockk(name, relaxed, *moreInterfaces, relaxUnitFun = relaxUnitFun) {
    mockkStatic(MongoCollection<*>::coroutine)
    val that = this
    every { coroutine } returns mockk(name, relaxed, *moreInterfaces, relaxUnitFun = relaxUnitFun) {
        every { collection } returns that
    }
    block()
}

inline fun mockkCoroutineDatabase(
    name: String? = null,
    relaxed: Boolean = false,
    vararg moreInterfaces: KClass<*>,
    relaxUnitFun: Boolean = false,
    block: MongoDatabase.() -> Unit = {}
): MongoDatabase = mockk(name, relaxed, *moreInterfaces, relaxUnitFun = relaxUnitFun) {
    mockkStatic(MongoDatabase::coroutine)
    val that = this
    every { coroutine } returns mockk(name, relaxed, *moreInterfaces, relaxUnitFun = relaxUnitFun) {
        every { database } returns that
    }
    block()
}
```

This would reduce the first lines to

```kotlin
val mockedMongoDb: MongoDatabase = mockkCoroutineDatabase()
val mockedMongoCol: MongoCollection<User> = mockkCoroutineCollection<User>()
// ...
```